# Can I load WebViews using Edge in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge

Just installed Nuget, "Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView" and trying to use the web browser "Edge" but when I am dragging the control into the form it gives me an exception:

> "Failed to create webview. The error is message following:
>   System.TypeLoadExcpetion: Could not find Windows.runtime type:   Could
>   not find windows.runtime type :
>   Windows.Web.UI.interop.WebViewControlProcess  at
>   microsoft.toolkit.Form.UI.Controls..WebView.get_Enterprise()'

is there any solution for this kind of error?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some of your code? It will help us understand your challenge.

Comment: Just added a screenshot , its UI control drag and drop error. this happens what I drap the control from toolbox !

Answer (score 3):

There are several [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#prerequisites) for using the toolkit controls in Windows Forms apps:

> - Visual Studio 2017.
> - Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17110 or a later release.
> - .NET Framework 4.6.2 or a later release.
> - Configure your application for high DPI support. To learn how, see this section of the guide.

Update to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017.

Update to the latest available version of Windows 10 (ideally the October 2018 update and later).

Make sure your project is targeting **.NET Framework 4.6.2 or later** by right-clicking the project in **Solution Explorer** and selecting **Properties**. I think this may be the most likely reason for your problem.

Enable HDPI support based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#high-dpi) guide.

Comment: I am using VS 2015

Comment: Then you definitely need to upgrade. The documentation explicitly says you need to use 2017, it is a prerequisite. You can get Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition for free.

Comment: Sure thing :-) . If that answered your question, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I am running VS 2015 and upgraded my .NET Framework to 4.8 and the webview and webviewcompatability controls both work just fine.